# Formula to Count Groups in a Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working in Excel, and, unfortunately, a strict requirement of this question is that the solution be done in Excel, preferably with formulas, but I'll try to convince others that VBA solutions are acceptable. I've been working with my buddy to try figuring a formula which will count the number of items based on frequency of repetition within a column, but for the life of me, I'm stuck.

Say you have a column of unique integer timestamps in the format YYYYMMDDHHMM. Every minute, MM, data is recorded to store an occurrence of the state of a variable (in this case weather). Weather states can be "storm", "clear", "fog", etc. Other columns have other states for other variables.

What I need to do is determine how long each state lasted.

I need the function to work regardless of the text value of the state so that I can use the same formula in other columns. As you might have guessed, this data set is tens of thousands of rows so I cannot do a subtotal as it breaks the data incorrectly, and involves too much manual copying and pasting, but it kinda does get to what I'm trying to do.

Say a column has 15 minutes of "fog", followed by 27 minutes of "rain", then 94 minutes of "cloud", etc, I need to know those group totals. If I could have the totals adjacent to the appropriate records (like every row within the fog group says "15" and every row within the rain group says 27, etc), that would be ideal.

**Edit:**

Added spreadsheet: [Example spreadsheet](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x3vc5d97es3aicv/SYS_XB03894_20181022.xlsx)

This sheet contains some weather data for a storm that occurred in 2018. The Weather and the "WFx Cat" fields are determined by data collected and the respective "count_" columns show how many consecutive times that item occurred until something changed.

Here is a snip from the middle of the sheet. Notice the 2's and the 8's in the counts. They are repeating over the entire group within the column to show the total number of items in that "section":

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: please post some sample data with desired results, without that it's very difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Sure thing! just updated with an example spreadsheet and image. Was unable to at time of posting. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution picture below, use a supporting column Temp1 (in Col C) and GroupCount (in Col D.

[image]

Set formulaes as below

Column C, C2: `=IF(B2=B1,C1+1,1)`
Column D, D2: `=IF(C2<C3,D3,C2)`

Copy the formulaes down all the way till end of your data.

Comment: Yes - this does what I want, and Ive come to a similar conclusion, but I need it to have the number repeating throughout the entire group. I added an example and screenshot for reference. Thanks for your input!

Comment: to repeat the values all you need to do it tweak the formula in col D, use D2 `=IF(C2<C3,D3,C2)`, and don't forget to drag it down all the way. Good luck!

Comment: sorry - not sure how I missed that, but yep. this definitely solves it, but, any advice for a one column solution?

Comment: @MrK, as much as I would have liked to, I'm not sure how to accomplish this using a single column. If this solves your problem (assuming that you do not get any better method), please don't forget to accept my solution.